# Making logo div a clickable link

Tags: html, css

I've got a logo and a second elements that are contained in divs sitting in the nav that I want to make links. Tried what seems like everything. It looks like the .logo svg div is linking but is running the full width of #topnav and the area with .logo is not clickable. The .nav container about div is not linking at all and I can't seem to get it to right align in the nav.

There are probable a few issues here (apologize for that) but any suggestions at all would be most appreciated.

HTML

```
<div id="topbar">
        <a href="##">
            <div class="logo svg">
                <object class="logo" type="image/svg+xml" data="img/gf_logo_main.svg">
                </object>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="###">
            <div class="nav container about">
                <object class="nav about" type="image/svg+xml" data="img/question mark.svg">
                </object>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    #topbar {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    color: #000;
}

.logo svg {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
}

.logo {
    height: 80%;
}

.logo img {
    border: 0;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav container about {
    position: absolute
    right: 0px;
}

.nav link about{
    height: 80%;
    }
```

Page is here:

http://www.glitteringfacade.com

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `<object>` tags for SVG any more. [Since IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-img), you can just inline it as a normal `<img>` (but be sure to specify its width and height, either as attributes or in CSS).

```
<a href="#" class="logo svg"><img src="img/gf_logo_main.svg"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks Blazemonger. Not sure if I implemented correctly but now the logo does not appear at all.   
  
HTML  
   ` <div id="topbar">
                    <a href="#" class="logo svg"><img src="img/gf_logo_main.svg"></a>
    </div>` 
  
CSS  
    .logo svg {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }

Comment: You also need to reorganize your CSS accordingly. `.logo svg` no longer exists, and for some reason you had `class="logo"` on both the container div and the svg element.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not following you. I am only using `.logo svg` now.

Comment: I think you meant to use `.logo.svg` or `.logo .svg` in your stylesheet?

Comment: Got it. Yes. Thanks Blazemonger.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a "link" using `onclick="window.location = 'http://www.yoururl.com';"` in your div tag and giving it the `cursor: pointer;` CSS style.

Comment: This "works" but its a hack that shouldn't be used if there's a better option (like Blazemonger's answer)

Comment: Thanks guys. Tried the first option to no avail.